# MySQL: Как получить последние записи одним запросом?

Tags: mysql, запрос

В таблице в хронологическом порядке фиксируются состояния пользователей (и их изменения), например,

```
datetime   | uid | status 
2016-07-01 | 14  | Register
2016-07-01 | 14  | Active
2016-07-02 | 15  | Active
2016-07-02 | 16  | Register
2016-07-02 | 14  | Pending
2016-07-04 | 16  | Pending
```

Как правильно сформулировать MySQL-запрос, чтобы в итоге получить

```
datetime   | uid | status  
2016-07-02 | 15  | Active
2016-07-02 | 14  | Pending
2016-07-02 | 16  | Pending
```

То есть как можно в MySQL-запросе указать, чтобы выводились только самые последние состояния для уникальных uid?
Пытался `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` и `MAX()`, но время выводит точно максимальное, а значение status – не максимальное.

**P.S.** Саму таблицу дал схематически, время фиксируется до секунды, пересечений по времени нет. Нужна просто последняя запись по каждому из uid. Буду благодарен за хотя бы подсказку, в каком направлении смотреть.

Comment: Выбрать сначала `select distinct uid`, затем inner join с той же таблицей чтобы получить дату и статус.

Comment: Вот популярный вопрос с подробными объяснениями http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: @cache, спасибо! Отличная ссылка, помогла. На неё не попал по поиску почему-то. Неожиданное решение с WHERE b.id IS NULL, но логичное.

Answer (score 3):

```
select uid, datetime, status
    from tablename
    join (
        select uid, max(`datetime`) as datetime 
            from tablename 
            group by uid
    ) lastvalues using(uid, datetime)
```

При условии уникальности (а лучше - уникального индекса) пары uid & datetime будет возвращать корректный результат.

Comment: Спасибо. А что за конструкция lastvalues? Никогда не встречал. Это LAST VALUES? Пытаюсь сейчас применить Ваши и из ссылки варианты.

Comment: lastvalues - это алиас. Вместо него (lastvalues) можно вписать любое имя идентификатора. Например `a` или `t`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT uid, max(`datetime`) as datetime,
       substr(max(concat(`datetime`,status)),20) as status
  FROM tablename
 GROUP BY uid
```

Смещение 20 в substr указано исходя из предположения, что поле datetime имеет тип данных datetime. Для других типов данных надо указать подходящее смещение исходя из длины поля даты в символьном представлении. Так же убедитесь, что при ваших региональных настройках при автоматическом преобразовании даты к строке компоненты идут в порядке год-месяц-день, для правильной сортировки.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, так:

```
SELECT max(`datetime`) as datetime, uid, status 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY uid
```

Не могу гарантировать, что это работает, как задумывалось (на тестовой выборке дало ок-результат), нужно стороннее подтверждение/опровержение

Comment: В дефолтном `mysql 5.7` запрос вообще не запустится и вернёт ошибку про обращение к неаггрегированному полю. В более старых версиях или после модификации sql_mode - datetime да, будет последний, а вот status - любой.

Comment: @Мелкий о, не зря я его ненавижу, значит