# Как сделать переменную в JOIN-е и использовать в HAVING?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо вывести название товара и итоговое количество каждого товара, оставшееся на складе, итоговое количество которого не менее исходного (за исходное считать первое поступление на склад) с сортировкой по итоговому количеству по убыванию.

Результат должен быть таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал такой запрос:

```
SELECT name, SUM(count) AS coount FROM `store`
LEFT JOIN `storetrans`
ON store.id = storetrans.id
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(count) < (SELECT `count` FROM `storetrans` WHERE `id` = 3 LIMIT 1)
```

И это работает, но только он берет первое значение НОЖНИЦЫ (я сам добавил id=3) для всех вещей.
А мне надо для каждого свой ID брал, вместо ID НОЖНИЦЫ (ID=3). Как можно сделать это ID динамичным?

Comment: количество на минимальную дату вытаскивать чем нибудь таким https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542765/194569 (применимо и в having) и тут же можно сравнивать с суммой

Comment: Версию сервера озвучьте.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на собственный вопрос. ПО больше прочитал как работает GROUP BY и HAVING.

```
SELECT store.id, store.name, SUM(storetrans.count) AS coount FROM `store`
LEFT JOIN `storetrans` ON store.id = storetrans.id
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(count) >= (
    SELECT `count`
    FROM `storetrans`
    WHERE `id` = store.id
    GROUP BY `id`
    HAVING MAX(`date`)
)
ORDER BY coount DESC
```

Спасибо [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)-у за подсказку!