# Помогите в SQL получить при join только максимальную дату из таблицы

Tags: sql, select, join

Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно приджоинить к таблице User таблицу UserLoginHistory так чтобы получить из нее страну по самой новой записи этого пользователя.
MySQL

User:

| id | mail | username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mailmail | Ivan |
| 2 | mail2mail | Irina |
| 3 | mail3mail | Pavel |

UserLoginHistory:

| id | country | datatime | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RU | 2020-03-01 15:36:44 | 1 |
| 2 | DE | 2022-03-01 15:36:44 | 1 |
| 3 | EN | 2019-03-01 15:36:44 | 2 |

Ожидаемый результат:

| userId | lastLoginCountry | mail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DE | mailmail |
| 2 | EN | mail2mail |

Пробую через PARTITION но что то работает не так, так как на MIN() или MAX() не реагирует.

```
SELECT u.id,
ulh.datatime,
MIN(ulh.country) over(PARTITION BY ulh.createdAt) as country FROM User u
LEFT JOIN UserLoginHistory ulh ON u.id = ulh.playerId GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: max/min от поля country берут именно значение этой колонки, а не относительно каких либо других полей. Кроме того, обратите внимание, что оконные функции (содержащие over) работают уже после group by и не видят значений в исходных строках до group by. Так что тут такие функции не применимы в принципе. Из оконных функций можно было бы применить first_value с нужным order by, но это надо было делать до группировки. А еще вы не указали какой именно sql вы используете. В некоторых диалектах бывают совершенно иные конструкции для решения подобных задач.

Comment: А еще не понятно что такое "самая новая запись", ведь поле даты в приведенном примере данных во всех записях одинаково

Comment: Спасибо! Самая новая запись именно по дате. Там различие в годе.

Comment: А, не заметил года :) Если диалект позволяет (MySQL >= 8.0.14), я бы сделал join lateral именно последней строки (подзапрос с limit). Если не позволяет, то либо перенести подзапрос в часть select, вместо join и так же использовать limit. Либо если используется все таки обычный join и group by то используются различные техники для достижения результата, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542685/

Comment: знаю что версия 8.0.

Comment: Пробую сделать через вложеный Select как описано. Запрос получился такой: SELECT u.id,
       (SELECT ulh.userId,
               ulh.country,
               ulh.createdAt
           from UserLoginHistory ulh
       group by ulh.userId
           having max(ulh.createdAt))
FROM User u
GROUP BY u.id.    Но считает не правильно все равно(

Comment: вложенный так запрос может вернуть только одно поле, вот страну и возвращаете. И он должен отобрать строго одну запись по нужному пользователю. Значит в нем нужен where который отберет нужного пользователя а еще order by createdAt  desc limit 1 что бы была одна последняя запись

Comment: А как во вложенный запрос можно передать текущего пользователя?

Comment: `where uhl.userId = u.userId`

Comment: Пробовал, выходит ошибка Unknown column 'u.id' in 'where clause  .  Запрос выглядит так: SELECT u.id,
       (SELECT
            ulh.country
           from UserLoginHistory ulh
       where u.id = ulh.userId
       group by ulh.userId
           having max(ulh.createdAt)
        order by ulh.createdAt desc limit 1)
FROM User u
GROUP BY u.id

Comment: А group by зачем ? Конечно после него никакого u уже не остается на фазе выбора колонок. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce34ad/1

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Реально заработало!